# Pandas - Slice between two indexes

Tags: pandas, slice

I need to process data with tensorflow for classification. Therefore I need to create DataFrames for each unit which was processed in my machine. The machine continously writes process data and also writes when a unit enters and leaves the machine.

A value in 'uid_in' means the unit with the logged number entered the machine, 'uid_out' means the unit left the machine.

I need to create a DataFrame like this for each unit processes by the machine.

```
[...]
        time  uhz1  uhz2  lhz1  lh2  uid_in  uid_out
5   08:05:00   201   200   101  100     1.0      NaN #Unit1 enters the machine
6   08:06:00   201   200    99  101     2.0      NaN
[...]
14  08:14:00   199   199    99  101    10.0      NaN
15  08:15:00   201   201   100  100    11.0      1.0 #Unit1 leaves the machine
[...]
```

How can I create the Dataframe df.loc[enter:leave] for each unit automatically?

When I try to pass a DataFrame.index it does not work in df.loc

```
start = df[df.uid_in.isin([123])]
end = df[df.uid_out.isin([123])]
unit1_df = df.loc[start:end]
```

Comment: `start` and `end` are `pd.DataFrame`s so they won't work in `df.loc`. You have to put `.index` at the end of them like this: `start.index`. You could also just say `start = df.uid_in.isin([123])` and `end = df.uid_out.isin([123])`.
Now my question: is the index for `start` and `end` one row? Or multiple? If multiple then this slice won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code almost worked out!

Original DataFrame:

```
        time  uhz1  uhz2  lhz1  lh2  uid_in  uid_out
0   08:00:00   201   199   100  100     NaN      NaN
1   08:01:00   199   199   100   99     NaN      NaN
[...]
5   08:05:00   201   200   101  100     1.0      NaN
[...]
55  08:55:00   241   241   140  140     NaN     41.0
[...]
58  08:58:00   244   244   143  143     NaN      NaN
59  08:59:00   245   245   144  144     NaN      NaN
```

New code:

```
start = df[df.uid_in.eq(1.0)].index[0]
end = df[df.uid_out.eq(1.0)].index[0]
unit1_df = df.loc[start:end]
print(unit1_df)
```

Output

```
        time  uhz1  uhz2  lhz1  lh2  uid_in  uid_out
5   08:05:00   201   200   101  100     1.0      NaN
6   08:06:00   201   200    99  101     2.0      NaN
[...]
14  08:14:00   199   199    99  101    10.0      NaN
15  08:15:00   201   201   100  100    11.0      1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you were pretty close. I modified your statements and picked out the start and end indices of `start` and `end`, as Ian indicated.

```
"""        time  uhz1  uhz2  lhz1  lh2  uid_in  uid_out
5   08:05:00   201   200   101  100     1.0      NaN
6   08:06:00   201   200    99  101     2.0      NaN
14  08:14:00   199   199    99  101    10.0      NaN
15  08:15:00   201   201   100  100    11.0      1.0
"""

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()

start = df.uid_in.eq(1.0).index[0]
end = df.uid_out.eq(1.0).index[0]

unit1_df = df.loc[start:end]
unit1_df
```

Output:

```
    time    uhz1    uhz2    lhz1    lh2     uid_in  uid_out
5   08:05:00    201     200     101     100     1.0     NaN
6   08:06:00    201     200     99      101     2.0     NaN
14  08:14:00    199     199     99      101     10.0    NaN
15  08:15:00    201     201     100     100     11.0    1.0
```

One-liner:

```
unit1_df = df.loc[df.uid_in.eq(1.0).index[0]:df.uid_out.eq(1.0).index[0]]
```

Comment: This returns the entire DataFrame on my machine. Altered the code a little and posted my solution.

Comment: Got it... hope it helped, at least! I changed my soln to match yours. cheers